# Error painting on iOS app 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, drawing

I'm developing an iOs 5 app where you can paint on a UIImageView inside a subview of the main view. When you paint the first 30px of the line doesn't follow your stroke. But what is really rare is that if you size up the ImageView and make it's size as all the screen 460x320 (although you don't see the full ImageView because is bigger than the view where it's inside.) it works fine. So maybe has a solution. That's my code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {   
    mouseSwiped = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        drawImage.image = nil;
        return;
    }

    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    lastPoint.y -= 10;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    mouseSwiped = YES;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.drawImage];
    currentPoint.y -= 10; // only for 'kCGLineCapRound'
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.drawImage.frame.size);

    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawImage.frame.size.width, drawImage.frame.size.height)]; //originally self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound); //kCGLineCapSquare, kCGLineCapButt, kCGLineCapRound
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5); // for size
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0); //values for R, G, B, and Alpha
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;

    mouseMoved++;

    if (mouseMoved == 10) {
        mouseMoved = 0;
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {      
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        drawImage.image = nil;
        return;
    }
    if(!mouseSwiped) {
        //if color == green
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.drawImage.frame.size);
        [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawImage.frame.size.width, drawImage.frame.size.height)]; //originally self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound); //kCGLineCapSquare, kCGLineCapButt, kCGLineCapRound
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
}
```

[image: That's what I get]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the first `touchesMoved:` is delayed by the API. I'm not sure anybody has been able to work around this issue yet.

Please file a bug report at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/

The real problem in your case is a simple mistake, though: You're using two different coordinate systems in `touchesBegan:` and `touchesMoved:`.

touchesBegan:

```
lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
                                 //////////
```

touchesMoved:

```
CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.drawImage];
                                            ///////////////
```

Comment: Sorry, now I've finished the sentence :) Read it now, I think you'll understand!

Comment: @MartiSerraVivancos Please do file a bug report about this behavior. Apple probably won't fix it if not enough people complain.

Comment: OK, I'll do it. But is there any way to paint/draw in an iOs app?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. As per your example above, you *are* already drawing. You'll have to find a way to smooth the first quarter of a second.

Comment: Because you don't get `touchesMoved:` events for the first quarter second. File a bug report!

Comment: Actually what really happens is that I draw an curve line (like the screen shoot) and the vertical line appears. But I start the line on the curve beginning. So I don't thin that I need to smooth. Do you understand me?

Comment: Here is a video of what happens http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sezyRWGzK7E&feature=youtube_gdata_player

Comment: I see. You're probably calculating your first point wrong. Check if you do this differently than the other points. Ah, there it is: In your `touchesBegan:`, you have `lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];`, and in `touchesMoved:` you have `CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.drawImage];`